# URL Rewrite behaving strange

Tags: .htaccess

Hi i have one of rewrite rules as below

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /cityres?city=$1 [L]
```

This makes URL like `http://example.com/value-of-city` and this works perfectly fine.

But here problem i am facing is that if user types

```
`http://example.com/anyrandomvalue`
```

then URL behave same as

```
`http://example.com/value-of-city`
```

and tries fetching results based on `anyrandomvalue`

How can i avoid same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict your regex to some allowed characters like a word character and hyphen:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /cityres?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I have my url as `http://example.com/delhi` ... now if user types `http://example.com/examplecity` then how will i differentiate. I know one method of adding prefixes but is there any other approach

Comment: Rules cannot differentiate between `delhi` and `examplecity`. Rule can just block `examplecity$` for example.

Comment: okies.. got u.. and how can i make sure that `folders` shall be excluded from this rewrite. example if i have folder of `images` then http://example.com/images shall not result in same URL.

Comment: Great... how can i add trailing slash if it is directory

Comment: Trailing slash is automatically added for a directory if `DirectorySlash` is not turned off

Comment: Thanks... my bad.. i turned it off :) .. now its working... i now will have check on cityres page if parameter is desired city otherwise redirect user